# Binomial Expansion $(1+kx)^4 (1+x)^n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

> **Question**
>
> In the expansion of $(1+kx)^4 (1+x)^n$, the coefficient of $x$ is $13$ and the coefficient of $x^2$ is $74$.
>   Find the possible values of $k$ and $n$.

**My solution**

$$
\begin{split}
(1+kx)^4 &= 1+4kx+6k^2 x^2+4k^3 x^3+k^4 x^4\\
(1+x)^n  &= 1+ \binom{n}{1}x+\binom{n}{2} x^2...
\end{split}
$$

So $\binom{n}{1}x + 4kx=13x$ and 
$\binom{n}{2}x^{2}+4k\binom{n}{1}x^{2}+6k^{2}x^{2}=74x^{2}$.

That is, $$\binom{n}{1}+4k=13 \quad (*)$$ and 
$$\binom{n}{2}+4k\binom{n}{1}+6k^{2}=74 \quad (**)$$

Since $\binom{n}{1}=n$, we have $n+4k=13$.

From trial and improvement I worked out that $n = 5$ and $k = 2$ satisfies both equations (*) and (**) above.

How do I find the other set of solutions?

Comment: The equation $n+4k=13$ only has four solutions over the non-negative integers: $(n,k) \in \{ (1,3),(5,2),(9,1),(13,0)\}$.

Comment: Since $n,k\in\Bbb N$, you only need to try a limited number of combinations.

Comment: nC2 = $n (n-1) / 2$

Comment: $\binom{n}2 = \frac 12 (n) (n-1)$. You have a quadratic equation as part of your system. Given the small numbers and limited number of possibilities, trial and error may be easier than solving formally.

Comment: Please can someone explain why n and k must both be natural numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The second equation gives
$$n(n-1) + 8nk + 12k^2 = 148$$
(by multiplying the equation by $2$ and noting $\binom n2 = \frac{n(n-1)}2.$

We have $n+4k=13$. Write $n = 13-4k$, and substitute this into the above equation, to obtain
$$(13-4k)(12-4k) + 8(13-4k)k + 12k^2 = 148,$$
which is a quadratic in $k$. You can now solve for $k$, and then use $n=13-4k$ to find $n$.

Comment: Please can you explain why n and k must both be natural numbers?

Comment: @mku My bad; only $n$ has to be integer, not necessarily $k$. I've edited my answer now.